# for() loop is not going to last

Tags: android, arrays, android-sqlite, android-looper

I have 6 records in the database project.
For loop that reads each record and then check the result of the transition to a dynamic array.
But
For loop can not continue until the end! For loop to examine the third record!

```
    int count = db.count_field("location", "id");

    geoAttrs = new ArrayList<StructureGeo>();
    StructureGeo geo = new StructureGeo();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        geo.lat = db.get_lat("location", i);
        geo.lang = db.get_log("location", i);
        geo.result = gps2m(latitude, longitude, geo.lat, geo.lang);
        geoAttrs.add(geo);
        Log.i("LOG", "Array Index #" + i + " = " + geoAttrs.get(i));
    }
    db.close();
    }
```

**edit :**

toast code after :

```
int count = db.count_field("location", "id");
```

and result :

[image]

Comment: Check your count size before looping.

Comment: Please check again ... I put photos on toast code

Comment: what does the logcat say about the `log` you have added inside the `for` loop

Comment: Are any of your fields in the database NULL? This could produce an error that drops out of the loop early

Answer (score 0):

The loop is okay. Insert a line that controls your count variable before the loop starts.

```
int count = db.count_field("location", "id");
    Log.d("LOG", "count equals " + count);
geoAttrs = new ArrayList<StructureGeo>();
StructureGeo geo = new StructureGeo();
```

if it's less than you expect, then check your db for bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you want the loop to check for 3rd item instead of full 6, this can be done by using a int variable like so:

```
int count = db.count_field("location", "id");

geoAttrs = new ArrayList<StructureGeo>();
StructureGeo geo = new StructureGeo();
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      counter++;
if(counter == 3){
   geo.lat = db.get_lat("location", i);
    geo.lang = db.get_log("location", i);
    geo.result = gps2m(latitude, longitude, geo.lat, geo.lang);
    geoAttrs.add(geo);
    Log.i("LOG", "Array Index #" + i + " = " + geoAttrs.get(i));
    break; // ends loop
   }


}
db.close();
}
```

Comment: No myfriend...
I want to fetch all records and record all the commands inside the loop to be done.
But the above code, only three are fetching record

Comment: ok, your code is fine, maybe your database has only 3 records with values.

Answer (score 0):

I anticipate your problem probably lies in the `db.count_field`, `db.get_lat` or `db.get_log` methods.

So could you please add them to your question.